# where does llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64 come from

Tags: clang, llvm, memcpy

i test clang and compile a simple C file including struct asigning.when I see the  LLVM code ,there is llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64 ,where is from ? I not see the defination only see its declare as a fucntion.

Answer (score 2):

It is a LLVM intrinsic function. As per the language reference:

> LLVM provides intrinsics for a few important standard C library
>   functions. These intrinsics allow source-language front-ends to pass
>   information about the alignment of the pointer arguments to the code
>   generator, providing opportunity for more efficient code generation.

The `llvm.memcpy` intrinsic specifically:

> The ‘llvm.memcpy.*’ intrinsics copy a block of memory from the source
>   location to the destination location.
>
> Note that, unlike the standard libc function, the llvm.memcpy.*
>   intrinsics do not return a value, takes extra isvolatile arguments and
>   the pointers can be in specified address spaces.